# 'c16rtomb' has not been declared in '::' (c++ in vscode)

Tags: c++, header-files

I'm trying to use the <bits/stdc++.h> header file in vs code for c++, which basically includes all the header files necessary if im not wrong (I'm pretty new to c++ so i might be wrong).
Now, whenever I try to compile a simple program it returns with the errors :-
file path for mingw - C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.1.0/cuchar:97:11: followed by the errors shown below.[image: Errors]

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

If I just include iostream it works fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: [Don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), copy-paste text *as text*. And please read [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Although `<bits/stdc++.h>` is bad practice the fact that you cannot include it when you are using a compiler that does support it would bother me. Possibly you have something misconfigured either in your compiler or in VSCode. No idea what that would be however. First step in tracking that down would be to try and compile your code outside of VSCode. If you still have problems then its definitely your compiler that is at fault.